# How to modify a string contained in an angular variable and shown in html

Tags: html, angular

I have a pre-compiled Angular site and I don't have the source code of it. I can see the following in one of its html pages:

```
<p>Download the file here: <a href="{{url}}">{{url}}</a></p>
```

the output of it is something like:

> Download the data here: http://site1.com/file1.txt

I would like to change in the HTML code to get something like:

> Download the data here: http://site2.com/file1.txt

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: That URL's dynamic, we can't see where it's coming from, so it's unclear where it should change. It may come from an API, for example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any possibility to do some string replace directly ? maybe like: {{url}}.toString().replace("site1","site2")?

Comment: You could try `{{url.replace("site1","site2")}}`, but that seems very hacky. If you don't actually have the source code or any proper development workflow, just randomly changing bits of your site is risky.